# Dynamic Xelement query in LINQ

Tags: linq-to-xml

I'm just wondering if it is possible to query a dynamic named xml element using LINQ.

See below sample XML doc:

```
<code>
<attendees>
<name>linda talor<name/>
<jur_a_credits>1.0<jur_a_credits/>
<jur_a_title>course 1<jur_a_title/>
<jur_f_credits>2.5<jur_f_credits/>
<jur_b_qualifier>self-study<jur_b_qualifier/>
<attendees/>
<code/>
```

I want now to select all xelement which contains a named "jur" then iterate the list to retrieves its value. Meaning,  I want to have below 
    
    1.0
    course 1
    2.5
    self-study
    
as in a collection so that I can iterate each of them to get there values.

Is it possible to query it in LINQ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure:

```
// You could use "Contains" instead of "StartsWith" of course
var query = doc.Descendants()
               .Where(x => x.Name.LocalName.StartsWith("jur"))
               .ToList();
```